# Removing square brackets from dictionary

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I am working from a dataframe and one of my columns has square brackets enclosing a dictionary. I am trying to remove square brackets to map items from the dictionary.

Looks like this:

```
[{'name': 'Steve', 'type': 'Candy', 'likes': '2', 'confidence': '0', 'country': {'confidence': '0.0', 'abrv': 'STV', 'name': 'USA'}, 'region': 'North Amercica', 'subregion': 'Southern Asia', 'state': {'confidence': '0.0', 'numer': '0000', 'name': 'Sindh'},'class': 'High School'}]
```

I tried using str.strip('[]']) but it makes a NaN.

Is there a way to just remove the square brackets and keep the information in tact?

Comment: You have one-element list. So `your_dict = your_list[0]`.

Comment: That means it's a list of dictionaries. Just index it with `[0]`.

Comment: @Barmar
Every row shows this type of list. My goal us to use the code below on every row in the column to extract the country name. I hae used this code successfully on the other columns which dont have the square brackets.

df.COLUMN.map(lambda x: x['country']['name'])

Comment: @nat-zad have you tried anything like `df.COLUMN.map(lambda x: x[0] if isinstance(x, list) and len(x)==1 else repr(x).strip('[]'))` ?

Comment: @Driftr95 thank you for your response & suggestion. This removes the square brackets and replaces them with quotation marks. `"{'name': 'Steve', 'type': 'Candy', 'likes': '2', 'confidence': '0', 'country': {'confidence': '0.0', 'abrv': 'STV', 'name': 'USA'}, 'region': 'North Amercica', 'subregion': 'Southern Asia', 'state': {'confidence': '0.0', 'numer': '0000', 'name': 'Sindh'},'class': 'High School'}"` I still can't extract from the row as I have in other columns & I am stuck. I only need the curly brackets in place. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *This removes the square brackets and replaces them with quotation marks.....I still can't extract from the row as I have in other columns & I am stuck. I only need the curly brackets in place.*

The quotes indicates that it's stringified; but the *`else repr(x).strip('[]')`* of my suggested expression only applied because it wasn't a list to start with, which means you need to attempt to parse it; so a `lambda` expression will no longer be enough. You could try something like **`df.COLUMN.map(try_parse)`** where `try_parse` is defined as:

```py
import ast
def try_parse(obj, unlistSingles=True, enforceType=None, defaultVal=None):
    if isinstance(obj, str) and enforceType!=str:
        try: obj = ast.literal_eval(obj) ## safer than just eval
        except: pass
    if isinstance(obj, list) and len(obj)==1 and enforceType!=list: obj = obj[0]
    if isinstance(enforceType,type):
        if isinstance(obj,enforceType): return obj
        try: obj = enforceType(obj)
        except: return defaultVal
    return obj
```

If you want to ensure that a dictionary is returned, use <kbd>**`df.COLUMN.map(lambda x: try_parse(x, enforceType=dict, defaultVal={}))`**</kbd> [or with `defaultVal={'country':{'name': None}}`]

---

Btw, about

> *I have used this code successfully on the other columns which dont have the square brackets. `df.COLUMN.map(lambda x: x['country']['name'])`*

If you want this to work for any dictionary at all without raising error, you can change the expression to <kbd>**`lambda x: getattr(x.get('country'), 'get', {}.get)('name', '!no_country_name!')`**</kbd> [you use a different default value than *`'!no_country_name!'`*, or just omit that part entirely, in which case the expression will return `None` if it can't get `x['country']['name']`].